# Show animation is not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm working on a function that hides, shows and replaces an element using an AJAX call. Everything works perfectly, it animates the closing but for some reason will not reanimate when it opens back up, it just appears. It's a rather long script, so this is important stuff:

```
 // This is the first part which is executed.
 var bar = $("#bar");

 // This is what happens when the bar is closes and works.

 if (!supressed) {
     bar.animate({height:0});
     bar.parent().animate({height:0}, function() {
         $(this).hide()
     });
 } else {
     // The bar is replaced with an identical div with the same id.
     bar.replaceWith(newBar);
     if (supressed) {
         // When the bar needs to appear again it runs the updateBar function.
        updateBar(true);
     }
}
```

And then here's the updateBar function. The #bar div just appears but will not animate into view. I've tried switching the order of the animation calls but neither seem to do the trick.

```
function updateBar(reload) {
    // Reassigns the variable
    var bar = $("#bar");

    if (reload === true) {

        // This is where things go wrong.
        bar.animate({height:"45px"});
        bar.parent().animate({height:"45px"}, function() {
            $(this).show();
        });
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1p80peqq/3/

Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by "opens back up"?  are you resetting values when closing?

Comment: @tq The idea is that it will animate open in the same manor that it closes. All the hiding/showing is happening in the example. Could it be that I'm replacing the html element after it has animated closed, so it no longer has the same height property?

Comment: Why don't you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Sure thing @OscarJara - You'll see after the initial replacement the  animations no longer function properly: https://jsfiddle.net/1p80peqq/3/ - I'm almost certain it has something to do with the CSS being nuked once I replace the DOM element, I'm just not sure the best way to go about resetting it back to a hidden state after it has been replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your original script, as per your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1p80peqq/3/) is that you are animating the height of the parent whilst it is hidden. Then you show it after the animation completes. So the height animation is not visible. You can tell this by inserting `console.log($(this).css('display'));` just before you show the parent. The console will display `none`.

I'm not sure why you also want to animate the parent. If you only want to hide/show the bar, you could do this:

```
function reloadBar() {
    var $bar = $("#bar");
    var $newBar = $("#new-bar");
    $bar.replaceWith($newBar);
    if ($("#click").hasClass("clicked")) {
        $newBar.animate({ height: 0 })
    } else {
        $newBar.animate({ height: '45px' });
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could change your `reload()` function to show the parent first before animating the height, like this:

```
function reload(option) {
    var $bar = $("#new-bar");
    if (option === true) {
        $bar.animate({
            height: "45px"
        });
        $bar.parent().show().animate({
            height: "45px"
        });
    }
 }
```

But there is redundancy in the above in that the animation of `$bar` does not make sense, since $bar is not visible (ie, `$bars`'s parent has `display: none`). So you could remove that completely like this:

```
function reload(option) {
    var $bar = $("#new-bar");       
    if (option === true) {
        $bar.css({ height: "45px" });
        $bar.parent().show().animate({
            height: "45px"
        });
    }
 }
```

Or you could simply animate the bar's height and leave the parent as is, like what I did earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `$(this).hide()` on the bar's parent sets its `display` property to `none`. Therefore, when you call `updateBar()` to animate the bar and its parent back into place, the parent remains hidden until *after* the animation completes and you call `$(this).show()`.

So in `updateBar()`, just call `bar.parent().show()` *before* you start the animation.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1p80peqq/6/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by hiding the parent of the bar before it's set to show. Like so:

```
bar.animate({height:"45px"});
bar.parent().animate({height:"45px"}, function() {
    $(this).hide.show("slow");
});
```